# Past tense questions in Middle English

Tags: questions, past-tense, middle-english

I am attempting to ask a question that would be in past tense using middle English. The specific question is of the form “Person, where did you find this thing?” I was not able to find much about questions in Middle English on the internet, or else I wouldn’t be asking here. Does anyone know how to say this or where to find an answer?

---

forgot to say the one thing i did find was that 2nd person would be something like thou findest

Comment: If Person is an adult of high status and the questioner is being polite then the second person plural "Where did you find this" is as correct for Middle English as it is for modern English. If Person is a child, a friend, a family member or someone of lower social standing then the second person singular "Where didst thou find this?" would have been used.

Comment: @BoldBen That looks more like Early Modern English to me. Depending on which stage of Middle English you’re talking about (orthography varies an awful lot between 1100 and 1500), something like “Hwer fand/fond þu/þou/thou þat/that?” would be more likely. (Also, in ME the subject form of _you_ would still have been _ye_, so the plural would have been something like “Hwer funden ye þat/that?”; _ye_ might have been written with a yogh, too, but I can’t type that on my phone.)